# Start Windows Service Unelevated

Tags: permissions, windows-services

I'm trying to create a Windows service that launches a batch file on a shared drive that is inaccessible from a process with elevated permissions. The user is a local admin, but I need to be able to start the service itself without admin permissions. Is this possible? Everything functions normally if I just run the file locally but the service seems to take the highest permissions available.

Example batch file:

```
S:
cd \some\shared\path
run.cmd
```

I've used NSSM to set it up for now but I'm willing to use something else if there's a native solution. Is there a way around this I'm not considering?

Comment: *that cannot be accessed with elevated permissions* ... Are you saying that not being able to access the shared drive with elevated permissions is the goal? Or that the shared drive is inaccessible when the process has elevated permissions?

Comment: That the shared drive is inaccessible if the process has elevated permissions.

Comment: Of course you can start a service as any user you want as long as the permission to run as a service is set.  Running a service as any admin (local or not) is a bad idea to begin with.  Have you thought about just using the task scheduler?

Comment: I have considered the task scheduler but unfortunately not allowed by the environment - but services are. Go figure. Similarly I would create a new user if I were allowed. Does that mean that there's no way to start a service with deliberately unelevated permissions? Can this be accomplished in a subprocess wrapper instead?